# ローカルIPでサイトが開かない

Tags: linux, debian, hosts

更新後、nodejs 上のプロジェクトが他のデバイスからローカル IP アドレス (localhost ではない) で開かなくなりましたが、実行しているラップトップではすべて正常に動作します。 ファイアウォールは使用しません。

```
npm run dev -- --host // どちらも機能しません
```

私のホストファイル:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   h1.org h1
#127.0.1.1  deb1.org deb1
#127.0.0.1   mainflask.net www.mainflask.net
#1.2.3.4         account.jetbrains.com

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
#192.168.250.1 master-node
#192.168.250.2 worker-node
```

debian 11 から 12 にアップグレードしました。アップグレードするときに、古い設定を新しいものに置き換えることに同意しましたが、どれがどれだったか覚えていません。誰かがそれを持っていたのではないでしょうか? これをどの方向に掘れば何ができるでしょうか？